# How to configure multipath using Intel X520-SR2 10GB on Oracle Linux 6.2?

Tags: linux, oracle, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, multipath

I've installed the Intel x520-sr2 Ethernet/Fibre card into a server that has Oracle Linux 6.2 Installed on it.  When I boot the server I can go into a QLogic menu (screen has something for Intel on copyrights so I believe this is the correct card but combined with QLogic Technology).  In the menu the two ports show up and I can see their MAC addresses.

Using Oracle Linux 6.2 (Basically Redhat 6.2), I need to setup multipath over a fibre network. I'm using a Dell Fibre Switch and can see the connections are plugged in and active from its GUI.  I need to find the WWN or IQN number for my storage device to setup the Initiator to grant access.  Not sure where to find that info on Oracle Linux?

Can I use SANsurfer or something like that to see the LUNs and connections?

After seeing the connections do I just install the multipath modules and it will find the paths, or is there more to do?

Comment: Have you read RedHat's Multipath manual? https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/DM_Multipath/ If you go step by step there you'll be able to setup a proper, resilient multipath system.

Answer (score 0):

Installing multipathd, and running multipath -v ; multipath -ll; should be sufficient to see what multipath devices you have. You can then add these to the /etc/multipathd.conf file to give them persistent names where needed.

Comment: I mostly use iscsi these days, but from what I can remember from my FC-days... powerpath, or sansurfer should give you your Lun information.